# Placing AR Anchors at a specific coordinate RealityKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

I'm making a **SwiftUI** application using **RealityKit**  where I need to put some anchors, and consequently some AnchorEntities, in AR at some particular coordinates, considering the point where I started the AR Experience (where the camera is being opened for the first time) as **origin**

I can't find a solution for this problem, though GeoLocation can be used to place those anchors on basis of their latitude and longitudes, GeoLocation isn't available in my location.

Thanks in advance!!